# Autofilter copy paste not all data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I’m trying to have my macro sort column L for DE42, and then copy the visible cells into column AL minus the header Undefined 3, to the last row of the table. I get it to sort but it copies the header and only pastes like half the data. Here’s what I have so far:

```
Sub DE42 ()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“Alerted Deduped”)
Range (“L1”).AutoFilter Field:=12 Criteria1:=“DE42”
Range(“AL2”).SpecialCell xlCellTypeVisible.Copy
Range.(“F2”).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by into a last row of a table?

This will simply filter and the copy the visible filter range to AL2 but if the filter is still on then some data may be hidden.

```
Sub DE42()

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Alerted Deduped")

        .Range("L1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="DE42"

        .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("AL2")

    End With

End Sub
```

Your original filter specified Field 12 so I am wondering if you actually meant to filter A1:L1 on field 12? I will update answer accordingly if so.

**Version 2** Assuming data starts column A

```
Option Explicit

Sub DE42()

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Alerted Deduped")

        .Range("A1").AutoFilter
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="DE42"

       .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 37).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("F2")

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Qharr, i will give that a try, but I basically want to sort my columns based on column L containing DE42 and then copy what ever the results are from column AL over to Column F minus the header. The issue is that I won’t know what rows remain after the filtering so I want it to copy any cells below the header of AL down to the last row of available data.

Comment: Qharr, I tried it and adjusted the field to 12, however it appears that it filters on column L and the copies all data from all columns and rows from column A-AL and pastes it into AL so it just pastes the whole data set. It should't be pasting anything into AL, just copying the contents of AL after filtering into column F.

Comment: I have put a version 2 up which takes data from AL after filter and puts it in column F. Let me know if that is what you meant>